# Bought a home, return air vents on ceiling have R19 insulation shoved in them?

Tags: heating, ducts

Checking filters and seeing what needs to be replaced, I opened the return air grate on the ceiling and what I find inside is a hunk of R19 insulation. Seems it should be some proper return air filter in here? Is this common?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Exchange. Where does this vent go? Might this instead be a whole-house fan, which isn't used (and  could leak heat) in winter? (Speaking of which, where are you located?)

Comment: Might there have been a new system installed that made the stuffed vents obsolete?

Comment: Thank you all for your patience. After crawling around in the attic I found that the duct that used to be connected to that vent is detached and no longer in use.